# RubberHose distorts a shape

Tags: after-effects, animation, plugins

I'm trying to animate a shape in After Effects with RubberHose plugin. I'm creating a shape layer and placing it in pre-compose. Then placing a 3 pins on that pre-compose. After I select them and alt+click on New RubberPin the shape is being distorted. Why is it happening?
[image: shape with pins]
[image: distorted shape]

Comment: I have not yet worked with the plugin, but I suspect that it accesses the path of your shape. If you pre-compose your shape, the plugin will not be able to access the path anymore. Try applying the plugin/effect on the shape directly before precomposing.

Comment: @FlorianClaaßen thank you